# D3: select element recently created not working?

Tags: d3.js

I create an element via d3, then try to select it to log a console/alert message :

```js
_body = d3.select("body");
_body.append("p")
    .attr("class","say-hello");
  
alert(_body.selectAll('.say-hello').length)
console.lof(_body.selectAll('.say-hello').length)
```

```css
p {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

It returns `undefined`. Meanwhile, I can SEE the element on my screen and dom. What do I miss ?

Comment: The selection isn't an array, to see how many items are in it you can use `selection.size()` as opposed to `selection.length`

Comment: Outch.... Thanks !